# Minimum Variance Portfolio problem

Tags: portfolio, portfolio-optimization, mean-variance

Minimum Variance Portfolio
Suppose there are N stocks in the investmentable universe and we have a fully invested portfolio investing 100% of the capital. The Covariance matrix is denoted as ∑.  We are interested in finding the portfolio with minimum variance. An investor choosing this portfolio is only concerned about the risk of the portfolio. Denoting a vector of ones by i=(1,….,1)^' ,  we have the following optimization problem:
$$Minimize   \frac{1}{2}w'∑w$$

$$Subject to : w’ .i = w_1 + w_2 +……+ w_N =1$$

I would like to solve above problem using Lagrangian multipliers.

Comment: What have you tried? [Google seems helpful](https://www.math.ust.hk/~maykwok/courses/ma362/Topic2.pdf).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this requires more effort from the OP.

Comment: Bob from your perspective it requires lot of efforts, but may be someone in the forum can answer...kindly keep it open.

Comment: No. Please put in some effort (Google, show attempts) then reopening could be considered.

Comment: There are several R packages that you can use to get the minimum variance portfolio.

Comment: @ Neeraj, Sir I know there are several packages in R, but I don't know much about R. I like if you can guide me from the scratch. I have 10 yrs of historical data in separate .csv file.

Comment: @AtulAgarawal You have to show some effort. We can only help you on specific issue. Your question appear to be more like a complete college assignment. BE SPECIFIC what you want to ask. Donot get demotivated if your question gets closed. Just show some effort from your side and we are always here to help you.

Comment: Thanks sir. My basics are clear but would like to understand how to construct portfolio in R. You can mail me few bullet points...if you can @ atul486@gmail.com.